# Adding a column with row numbers to a list in a loop

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, uwp

I tried to create a view with results from a query to an SQLite database. I can create an `ObservableCollection` "Results" with the required data. This data is sorted and ready for the view. But I need an extra column that displays the rank of the row, based on the index of the list +1.

I tried to do this with a `IEnummerable` collection, creating a new list with the added column. This works but I can't empty the `Enummerable` list. This is a problem when selecting a new index when `klasseDropDown_SelectionChanged` method is called. The list will not update to the new query data. How to simplify this?

My code:

```cs
namespace GolfComp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class HomePage : Page
    {

        ObservableCollection<WedstrijdModel> wedstrijden = new ObservableCollection<WedstrijdModel>();
        ObservableCollection<TeamModel> results = new ObservableCollection<TeamModel>();
        ObservableCollection<KlasseModel> klassen = new ObservableCollection<KlasseModel>();
        IEnumerable<object> resultaat;
        public HomePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
            WireUpDropdown();

            if (Datagrid.ItemsSource == null)
            {
                Datagrid.ItemsSource = resultaat;
            }
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Klasse ORDER BY Klasse_Id";
            var klasselijst = SqliteDataAccess.LoadData<KlasseModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());
            klasselijst.ForEach(x => klassen.Add(x));
        }
        private void LoadStand()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Team WHERE KlasseId = @KlasseId ORDER BY PuntenVoor DESC LIMIT 10";
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "@KlasseId", klasseDropDown.SelectedValue}

            };
            var spelerlijst = SqliteDataAccess.LoadData<TeamModel>(sql, parameters);
            spelerlijst.ForEach(x => results.Add(x));

            int i = 1;
            var result = from curRow in results
                        orderby curRow.PuntenVoor descending
                        select new
                        {
                            Stand = i++,
                            curRow,
                            Teamnaam = curRow.Team_Naam,
                            Punten = curRow.PuntenVoor
                            
                        };

            resultaat = result.ToList();
        }

        private void WireUpDropdown()
        {
            klasseDropDown.ItemsSource = klassen;
            klasseDropDown.DisplayMemberPath = "Competitie";
            klasseDropDown.SelectedValuePath = "Klasse_Id";
            klasseDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void klasseDropDown_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            results.Clear();    
            LoadStand();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear an `IEnumerable<T>`, because it is not a collection. It contains one method

```cs
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<out T> GetEnumerator ();
```

which returns an enumerator object allowing you to enumerate a sequence. This sequence can be obtained from a collection or can be generated algorithmically with [yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield).

Instead, type the result variable as

```cs
System.Collections.IList resultaat;
```

This allows you to empty it with

```cs
resultaat.Clear();
```

However, I am not sure how you are going to use the objects in this list, since you have no type name you can use to cast them to a useful type.

Comment: I followed you instructions and I am indeed struggling with the type. When debugging I see the proper number of items [count = 10] but no values in the listview. Can you point me in a direction to cast the proper type? If I have a collection it should do the job with a telerik datagrid.

Comment: Anonymous types are mainly used locally for temporary results. Since they have no type name, their usage outside of the defining method is very restricted. Create your own class instead. Or use ValueTuples.